# Grails in ubuntu server

Tags: grails, ubuntu-server

I have a point of sale made in Grails. I need it to connect to Ubuntu Server, but I really don't know how to do this. I'm completely lost

Comment: we are lost too.  SO is a FAQ site.  please state a concrete problem (the errors you get, the things you have tried etc).  if this is really how to install your software on said ubuntu box, you might be better off asking this question on the superuser SE.  there are several things involved (installting software, setting up firewall, maybe a reverse http proxy, ...).  if you have concrete problems, please also state in your question, if you plan to roll out a war in a container or a fatjar (e.g. grails3)

Comment: i need to do a point of sale with a server.
I already have made all the point of sale but I need that it connets with a server, but the server should be ubuntu sever.

Answer (score 1):

SIDE NOTE

Please make your steps what you have done and the question you are asking as accurately as possible otherwise we are grasping at straws what you want.
If this answer is not what you want please make your question clear.

ANSWER
I am guessing you want to connect to an ubuntu server using grails?

If so please check out this plugin: https://grails.org/plugin/remote-ssh
.

Comment: i need to do a point of sale with a server. I already have made all the point of sale but I need that it connets with a server, but the server should be ubuntu sever.

Comment: i need to do a point of sale with a server. I already have made all the point of sale but I need that it connets with a server, but the server should be ubuntu sever.